# Emacs keyboard bindings in MATLAB: Copy/Paste?

Tags: matlab

In Emacs, a user would usually copy/cut text as follows:

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of the text to be copied/cut with one of the move-cursor commands (e.g. `C-p`, `C-n`, `C-f`, `C-b`, `M-f`, `M-b`, etc.)
2. **Set a mark with `C-spacebar`** (in Emacs this command is also called `set-mark`)
3. Move to the end of the text to be copied/cut using move-cursor commands.
4. Copy `M-w` or Cut `C-w` the text from the mark to the current cursor location
5. Move the cursor to the place where the copied/cut text is to be inserted
6. Paste the text with `C-y`

[Starting in R2009a](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/09/28/configurable-keyboard-shortcuts-have-arrived/), MATLAB supports [customizable keyboard shortcuts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br6h4bl), including a pre-defined Emacs layout.

My question is: Does MATLAB support a `set-mark` command such as `C-spacebar` (step 2. above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MATLAB currently doesn't support `set-mark`.

Comment: you could write the m code in emacs right? and use emacs as an editor, but the big losses are that you don't have the code highlighting and filling, or the debugger; right?

Comment: @Vass there is actually an emacs-mode maintained by a MathWorks employee. I haven't tried using the debugger within Emacs though, it used to be available, but I guess they killed it (emacslink).